# Inserir um array dentro de uma Key Json

Tags: c#, json, array

Preciso obter um Json da seguinte forma:

```
{
    "razao_social": "Loja do Zé LTDA",
    "nome_fantasia": "Zé Store",
    "tipo": "J",
    "observacao": "Cliente com ótimo histórico de pagamentos.",
    "emails": [
        {
            "email": "jose@zestore.com.br"
        },
        {
            "email": "marcos@zestore.com.br"
        }
    ],
    "telefones": [
        {
            "numero": "(11) 98765-4321"
        },
        {
            "numero": "(47) 9876-5432"
        }
    ]
}
```

O email teria de ser um array?

Como seria o código para isso?

Minha Classe

```
public class GetClienteBO
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string razao_social { get; set; }
    public string nome_fantasia { get; set; }
    public string tipo { get; set; }
    public string cnpj { get; set; }
    public string Inscricao_estadual { get; set; }
    public string suframa { get; set; }
    public string rua { get; set; }
    public string complemento { get; set; }
    public string cep { get; set; }
    public string bairro { get; set; }
    public string cidade { get; set; }
    public string estado { get; set; }
    public string observacao { get; set; }
    public Email emails { get; set; }
    public Telefones telefone { get; set; }
    public bool excluido { get; set; }
}

public class Email
{
    public string email { get; set; }
}

public class Telefones
{
    public string numero { get; set; }
}
```

Código:

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public void JsonTeste(string JsonChamada)
{
    SerializerFO Serializer = new SerializerFO();
    var Retorno = new GetClienteBO();

    Retorno.id = 1;
    Retorno.razao_social = "Loja do Zé LTDA";
    Retorno.nome_fantasia = "Zé Store";
    Retorno.tipo = "J";
    ...

    Retorno.estado = "SC";
    Retorno.cidade = "Joinville";
    Retorno.excluido = true;
    Retorno.observacao = "Cliente com ótimo histórico de pagamentos.";
    Retorno.emails = ????
    Retorno.telefones = ???
    ...            
}
```

Comment: **Sim**. É essa a dúvida?

Comment: Também, gostaria de saber como implementaria isso?

Comment: Implementaria o que? Você só jogou um JSON na pergunta ***=)***

Comment: Como seria o código kkkkk desculpe XD

Comment: Jovem, como seria o código pra quê? Criar o JSON? Você já tem as classes prontas? O que você tem pronto?

Comment: Editei o post com meu código, preciso saber como eu vou passar os valores em emails e telefones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sim, é possível.

Na classe `GetClienteBO`, mude

```
public Email emails { get; set; }
public Telefones telefone { get; set; }
```

para

```
public List<Email> emails { get; set; }
public List<Telefone> telefones { get; set; }
```

Assim ao invés das propriedades receberem apenas uma instância de `Email`/`Telefone`, elas receberão coleções destes tipos.

No método de atribuição, faça

```
Retorno.emails = new List<Email> 
                 { 
                     new Email { email = "user@teste.com" },
                     new Email { email = "email@teste.com" },
                 };
Retorno.telefones = new List<Telefone> 
                    { 
                        new Telefone { numero = "30005000" },
                        new Telefone { numero = "88996654" } 
                    };
```

É importante você notar que não está seguindo os [padrões de nomenclatura do C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xzf533w0(v=vs.71).aspx). Também acho interessante você renomear a classe `Telefones` para `Telefone` (veja que eu usei este padrão no minha reposta) porque a classe representa **um número de telefone** e não vários. Já a propriedade, deveria se chamar `Telefones` (no plural), acho que você acabou invertendo os conceitos.

Outra coisa importante: se você vai usar apenas uma propriedade (como mostra nas classes `Email` e `Telefones`), seria mais fácil criar diretamente uma propriedade como `List<string>` na sua classe principal. Claro que isso depende de todos os outros detalhes da sua aplicação, isso é só uma dica.

Algo como:

```
public List<string> Emails { get; set; }
public List<string> Telefones { get; set; }
```

Comment: Ah sim! Entendi! Mt obrigado!!

Comment: Saquei! Mas por exemplo, preciso enviar esse json via http, a aplicação que recebe o json, por padrão tem que ir da forma que eu escrevi (Emails e Telefones), definindo como `List<string>` não iria interferir no resultado do Json não?

Comment: Iria mudar sim, porque a propriedade `emails` não teria objetos dentro dela, e sim um array de strings

Comment: Entendi! Obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: Sempre à disposição ***=)***.